# Filter the user's keyboard input into JTextField (swing)

Tags: java, swing

How can I limit the keyboard input before it will be entered into JTextField (swing)

I want to allow user to input only 
"+-0123456789abcdef,." chars, and no more than 1 `,` or `.` char

My JTextField is one-line input field.

thanks!

Comment: similar to http://stackoverflow.com/q/725823/196561

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can achieve this by [DocumentFilter](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/javax/swing/text/DocumentFilter.html). This allows you to control text handling for any Document type.
Or use a [JFormattedTextField](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/formattedtextfield.html)