# Set DocumentFilter on JOptionPane

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield, joptionpane, documentfilter

I'm using:

```
String s = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(...);
```

to get a response back from the user to a question; the dialog is set up to display a text field for the response. I'd like to limit the characters allowed in the response to alphanumeric and '_' only. Is it possible to install a DocumentFilter on the text field without implementing my own custom dialog from scratch?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4684914/filter-the-users-keyboard-input-into-jtextfield-swing

Answer (score 3):

Access the autocreated text field of JOptionPane is theoretically possible, but it's IMHO wrong way.

Here is the better solution:
JOptionPane has a hidden feature: it accepts also Swing components as messages. So you need to create a panel with lable and text field (with your DocumentFilter) and pass it to a confirm dialog. After confirmation you can read the text from your text field.

Here is sample:

```
JPanel p = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());
JTextField fld = new JTextField(10);
// set document filter for 'fld' here
p.add(new JLabel("Enter text: "));
p.add(fld);
int val = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, p, "Test", JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION, JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE, null);
if (JOptionPane.OK_OPTION == val) {
  System.out.println("Text: "  + fld.getText());
}
```

Comment: I don't know about hidden, as I'm pretty sure it's in the docs, most people just seem to miss it ;)...+1

Answer (score 2):

Not sure how to add a DocumentFilter to the text field document directly.

See [Stopping Automatic Dialog Closing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html#stayup) for a different approach.