# How to check an empty Double JTextField

Tags: java, swing

I've been working this for 2 days but I can't still figure how to check if the jtextfield is empty (`Double` not `String`) before passing it to my database.

I figured it out how to validate `String` if the field is empty, but I need to put the right code on how to validate `Double` if the field is empty.

Thanks in advance.

Here's my code:

```
private void saveButton3ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    String inventcodef = inventCodeField.getText();
    String inventnamef = inventNameField.getText();
    String categ = cmbname.getSelectedItem().toString();
    double inventreorderf = Double.parseDouble(inventReorderField.getText());

    ..............
    if ((inventCodeField.trim().Length()==0) ||       (inventNameField.trim().Length()==0)
```

Comment: How about `inventReorderField.getText().trim().length == 0` or `inventReorderField.getText().isEmpty()` condition? But still doesn't guarantee that entered value is double parsable, Better to use JFormattedTextField.

Comment: Hello Harry joy/ I just usd  inventReorderField.getText().trim().length == 0 it says an error and inventReorderField.getText().isEmpty() but it doesn't return anything. thank you!

Comment: thanks harry I'll try the JFromattedTextField :)

Comment: Never do getText().trim().length, with JTextField or anything related to that, always use getDocument().getLength(), then do your stuff on that.

Comment: @GagandeepBali Hello, please correct me if I'm wrong. is getDocument().getLength() use for validating if the JTextField is empty? Thank you!

Comment: @mix : True it is used to know that thing. If the result is > 0, then JTextField is not empty, else it is :-)

Comment: thank you so much! :) I'll try this one :)
is it working with DOUBLE?

Comment: @GagandeepBali hello. I tried inventReorderField.getDocument().getLength()==0 (it is double) but it doesn't work but for string it works fine :)

Comment: @mix : The thing I told you is used to check the length of the stuff inside the input Fields, i.e. JTextField, JTextArea etc. For checking Double I guess the answer you selected is the right one JFormattedTextField can do that part.

Comment: @mix : Your Welcome and Keep Smiling :-)

Comment: Hi @GagandeepBali i have problem , how can I save / declare the jformatted text?  if i'll replace the  double inventreorderf = Double.parseDouble(inventReorderField.getText());

Comment: @mix : Yeah true, that's the way to go :-)

Comment: @mix : Or you can do like this, try {Document document = inventReorderField.getDocument(); int len = document.getLength(); double inventreorderf = Double.parseDouble(document.getText(0, len));} catch(BadLocationException ble){ble.printStackTrace();}

Comment: hi @GagandeepBali should I put them inside

private void saveButton3ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt)? 

I'm sorry I'm just a student in java. You're help is very much appreciated. I'm thankful :)

Comment: @mix : Exactly inside the code that you had written in your question, too true saveButton3ActionPerformed(...). No worries, I am always there to help :-) Your Welcome.

Comment: @GagandeepBali it says BadLocationException cannot find symbol :)

Comment: @mix : import javax.swing.text.BadLocationException, at the start of your program.

Comment: @GagandeepBali it works now! thank you so much! I've been searching for this for a couple of days :)

Comment: On Stack Overflow, it is not necessary to tag a question as solved. By marking an answer accepted, that's enough to designate your question as solved, so I've rolled back your subsequent edit.

Comment: Your Welcome and Keep Smiling :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To enforce formatting (numeric etc) you can use [JFormattedTextField](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/formattedtextfield.html).

To ensure values are not blank see [No blanks in JTextField](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/725823/no-blanks-in-jtextfield)

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong but I think JFormattedTextField (for numeric) is used to validate if the the value entered is NUMERIC or not. Does it detect if the user didn't input any value? thank you so much

Comment: exactly, that's why DOUBLE JTEXTFIELD in your subject looks strange

Answer (score 2):

You are reading the `double` at first as a `String`. So, you can do something like this:

```
double inventreorderf;
if (inventReorderField.getText().trim().length == 0)
{
    //Do something which should happen when the field is empty
}
else
{
    try
    { 
        inventreorderf = Double.parseDouble(inventReorderField.getText());
    }

    catch (Exception e)
    {
        //The user has entered an invalid number. Notify him/her here.
    }
}
```

Comment: but where should I put those code? does it need to be inside the SAVEBUTTONACTION? sorry I'm new in java. :)

Comment: @mix: Yes this needs to be put in the event handler, instead of this line: `double inventreorderf = Double.parseDouble(inventReorderField.getText());`. Note that to my knowledge the `JFormattedTextField` only checks of the format of the input, and not if the field is empty or not.

Comment: Does it works even if I change jtextfield into jformattedtext?

Comment: @mix: The `JFormattedText` extends the `JTextField`, so you should be able to get it to work.