# JTextField - how to determine which values can be typed

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield

I developing some calculator, so in the `JTextField` above can have only some characters.
What is the best way to make that happened?

Let's say that I have this `char[] values = 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,+,-,*,/,(,),.,` which those are the values which the user can type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually I managed to create my own `JTextField` which implemented like this:

```
public class MyTextField extends JTextField {

    //final value for maximum characters
    private final int MAX_CHARS = 20;

    /**
     * A regex value which helps us to validate which values the user can enter in the input
     */
    private final String REGEX = "^[\\d\\+\\/\\*\\.\\- \\(\\)]*$";

    public MyTextField(){

        //getting our text as a document
        AbstractDocument document = (AbstractDocument) this.getDocument();        

        /**
         * setting a DocumentFilter which helps us to have only the characters we need
         */
        document.setDocumentFilter(new DocumentFilter() {
            public void replace(FilterBypass fb, int offs, int length, String str, AttributeSet a) throws BadLocationException {

                String text = fb.getDocument().getText(0, fb.getDocument().getLength());
                text += str;

                if ((fb.getDocument().getLength() + str.length() - length) <= MAX_CHARS && text.matches(REGEX)){
                    super.replace(fb, offs, length, str, a);
                } 
            }

            public void insertString(FilterBypass fb, int offs, String str, AttributeSet a) throws BadLocationException {

                String text = fb.getDocument().getText(0, fb.getDocument().getLength());
                text += str;

                if ((fb.getDocument().getLength() + str.length()) <= MAX_CHARS && text.matches(REGEX)){
                    super.insertString(fb, offs, str, a);
                }
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3):

Use a `JFormattedTextField`. You can use a `MaskFormatter` with the `setValidCharacters(...)` method and specify a String containing valid characters.

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Using a MaskFormatter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/formattedtextfield.html#maskformatter) for more information.

Or the other approach is to use a JTextField with a `DocumentFilter`. Read the Swing tutorial on [Implementing a DocumentFilter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/generaltext.html#filter) for more information.

Comment: @RoeyGolzarpoor,  You can search the forum or the web for code that uses that method. I'm sure you will find an example.

Answer (score 2):

There are already several solved questions like yours:

[Filter the user's keyboard input into JTextField (swing)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4684914/filter-the-users-keyboard-input-into-jtextfield-swing)

[No blanks in JTextField](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/725823/no-blanks-in-jtextfield)

According to these, you should use a DocumentFilter or a JFormattedTextField.

Comment: I can't find some example which is using `char[]` as a valid input

Comment: Well, if you choose to use the DocumentFilter, you could verify for every character typed by the user if this is contained or not in your char array.

Comment: Try to take a look at this for a good example about how use it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24844559/jtextfield-using-document-filter-to-filter-integers-and-periods